# Proof for smallest sigma field to contain a class of subsets of the sample space of an experiment.

Tags: probability-theory

I've started studying theoretical probability and came across this statement that

Given a class of subsets e of the sample space X of an experiment E, the intersection of all sigma fields of subsets of X that contain e is the smallest sigma-field containing the class e.

I tried but was unable to come up with a proof for this.

I figured that the smallest sigma-field to contain the class e would be one in which we add the complement of each element of e to e and then adding the countable unions of elements of e to e until we get a sigma-field.

But I was unable to go from here to the proof.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Rather than trying to explicitly construct the smallest $\sigma$-field containing $e$, you could show that any other $\sigma$-field which contains $e$ also contains the intersection.

Comment: That's simple enough! Stupid of me not to think of it. Thanks @AdamSaltz